# Tab title is wrong with ssh/screen on osx

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, gnu-screen, terminal.app

I am doing

```
ssh -t host screen -D -RR
```

in OS X (10.9) terminal tabs.

My `~/.screenrc` is identical on all remote hosts and contain the following line:

```
hardstatus string "%H(%n:%t)$USER %h"
```

My `~/.bashrc` is also identical on all hosts.

When I login to host `host_u` (`Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS`) running `Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06`, the tab title on the OS X terminal is `host_u(1:bash)sds ~`, as expected.

When I login to host `host_c` (`CentOS release 6.3 (Final)`) running `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`, the tab title on the OS X terminal is `~/FooBar` (which is the local OS X directory from which I ran the `ssh/screen` command.

**Problem**:  the `hardstatus` line does not work on `host_c`.

**Additional information**:

`.screenrc`:

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

On both `host_c` and `host_u`, `TERM` is `xterm-256color` (inherited from the OS X terminal).

Comment: I gave up on `screen` a few months ago and just bit the bullet and moved to `tmux`. No promises it'll fix this issue, but actively-maintained software almost always beats 7-year-old software.

Comment: At a guess, the termcap/terminfo DB on host_c machine doesn't have the correct content. What's $TERM set to? Does `tput ts && echo -n OMG && tput fs` set the title correctly? Does your `.screenrc` contain any `termcap`/`terminfo`/`termcapinfo` lines?

Comment: @Gabe: `tput ts` --> `tput: unknown terminfo capability 'ts'`

Comment: OK, that's a bit weird. If you log in to host_c and can set the title with: '`echo -e "\033];TITLE GOES HERE\007"`', try adding this line to your screenrc: "`termcapinfo xterm* 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007'`". I'll guess that it or something similar is present in `/etc/screenrc` (or `/usr/local/etc/screenrc` or whatever) on host_u.

Comment: @Gabe: yes, almost. adding `termcapinfo xterm* 'hs:ts=\E]0;:fs=\007:ds=\E]0;\007'` to `host_c:~/.screenrc` solved the problem. Please transform your comments into an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the hardstatus, screen needs to know the correct escape codes to send to the terminal (emulator); they're found via termcap/terminfo. The relevant capabilities are:

- `hs` - If set, the terminal supports a hardstatus line
- `ts` - move the cursor to the hardstatus line ("begin")
- `fs` - move the cursor back to where it was before ("finish")
- `ds` - how to clear/reset the hardstatus ("default").

Nobody has a real "hardstatus" line any more. To use the title of an xterm or other GUI emulators, the capabilities need to be set; to avoid confusing programs, they're not set in the normal termcap/terminfo databases. You could add them there, or you can tell screen what they would be if they were set, in your .screenrc:

`termcapinfo xterm* 'hs:ts=\E]0;:fs=\007:ds=\E]0;screen\007'`
(This sets a default title of "screen", which is unlikely to be relevant. The actual escape codes may differ depending on your terminal emulator - in particular, for some xterm variants the `0` in `\E]0;` may not be required, or may need to be a different value; check your terminal emulator's man-page.)

These settings will be used by screen, but not be available to any other apps; e.g. if you had an editor that wanted to override the hardstatus, it would look up the real termcap, find `hs` unset (or whatever the system default is) and know not to do that.